# Issues with creating a "many-to-many" relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I'm trying to do a simple task : I created a "magazine" scaffold, but I want it to have a specific relation : a user can have participate for the creation / redaction of a magazine, and it can take several users to create a magazine.

I checked the APIDock and did the following:

1. Specified the relation between the magazines and the users

**model/magazine.rb**

```
class Magazine < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :thumbnail, ThumbnailUploader
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**model/user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :magazines

  # More code...
end
```

2. Created a migration to add a table to link both the models

   ```
   class ManyToMany < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
       def change

           create_table :magaziness_users, :id => false do |t|
             t.integer :user_id
             t.integer :magazine_id
           end

       add_index :magazines_users, [:magazine_id, :user_id]
     end
   end
   ```

Then I ran the migration

3. Added the list of all users ever recorded to the database to create a dropdown

   ```
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :users %>
     <%= f.select :users, User.all_except(current_user).collect {|u| [u.username, u]}, {prompt: 'Add a creator?'}, { :multiple => true, :size => 3 } %>
   </div>
   ```

But, when I'm saving a new magazine, the user doesn't get saved, and the "magazines_user remains empty.

**edit 1**

This is an auto-generated controller, since I use the scaffold command to create it. I didn't touch anything excepted the `set_magazine` function, where I added the Friendly_Id

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_magazine, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @magazines = magazine.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @magazine = magazine.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @magazine = magazine.new(magazine_params)

    if @magazine.save
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'magazine was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @magazine.update(magazine_params)
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'magazine was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @magazine.destroy
    redirect_to magazines_url, notice: 'magazine was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private
    def set_magazine
      @magazine = magazine.friendly.find(params[:id])
    end

    def magazine_params
      params.require(:magazine).permit(:titre, :description, :apercu, :users)
    end
end
```

Did I forget any step?

Comment: Please post your controller code.

Comment: I added the controller

Comment: I have never used this approach for many to many relations....A better approach would be to use "has many through"......Read about it here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: The problem is that I don't really need an other entity, I just need to state who participated to which magazines, and which magazines can be found on who's profil..

Comment: Don't you have a typo in your migration: create_table :magaziness_users ? Also it is strange that in your controller your have "magazine.new" shouldn't it be: Magazine.new?

Comment: I didn't copy / paste my file because I add to edit out some details, but I guarantee you there isn't any typo in the original file, I just checked it

Comment: Have you tried to manually create a magazine with users directly in a rails console to see what happens? Also don't hesitate to use the "explain" method to see what rails is doing exactly in DB: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-explain

Comment: Ok so i did the following : `Magazine.create(titre: 'Slacky Mag', thumbnail: 'lel.jpg', description: 'For guys', users: User.first).explain`
I didn't really know how to select a user, so I improvized. Got the following: 
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'each' for #<User:0x0000000810d5a8>`

Comment: It should rather be: `mag = Magazine.create(titre: 'Slacky Mag', thumbnail: 'lel.jpg', description: 'For guys')` then : `mag.users << User.first` and finally: `mag.users.explain` to see the SQL request to get users from mag. Of course a User must already exists for this to work. :)

Comment: Ok, but is my User selection good ? I'm still gettting the error "undefined method each for #<User>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130683/discussion-between-kulgar-and-jaeger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so here is the answer with my code working:

I did two scaffolds:

```
rails generate scaffold user username:string email:uniq password:digest
rails generate scaffold magazine title:string description:text preview:string
```

Then added this to magazine migration:

```
create_table :magazines_users, id: false do |t|
  t.belongs_to :magazine, index: true
  t.belongs_to :user, index: true
end
```

In my form, I added:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :users %>
  <%= f.select :user_ids, User.all.collect { |u| [u.username, u.id] }, {include_blank: true}, {multiple: true} %>
</div>
```

And in my magazines controller I only modified magazine_params:

```
def magazine_params
  params.require(:magazine).permit(:title, :description, :preview, :user_ids => [])
end
```

To see that it works, I added this in magazin show view:

```
<p>
  <strong>Users:</strong>
  <%= @magazine.users.map(&:username).join(" - ") %>
</p>
```

Of course I added "has_and_belongs_to_many" as you did in User and Magazine models.

And that's it :) 
Tested with Rails 5 and it works just fine. :)

Also I strongly advice you to take a look at [the simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). It has some great methods to handle associations (like has_and_belongs_to_many) easily, like this : `<%= f.association :users, collection: User.all_except(current_user).order(:username) %>`

Comment: I have an issue with what you propose: when i try to load magazine#new, i get `undefined method 'users_ids' for #<Magazine:0x0000000de49eb0>`.. I don't know if it has something to do with the migration or something else

Comment: Why do you have "users_ids"? Take a look at your form, it should be "user_ids" :)

Comment: You're totally correct !! But now I have another issue, that I got when trying to create my many to many association earlier : `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (User(#139695920) expected, got NilClass(#10121780))`

Comment: Double check your form. Check also sent params in Rails log. It seems that rails doesn't manage to find the user to link to magazine. Missing `u.id` in your form perhaps? As my solution work, you'll have to dig in and try to find why it doesn't work for you. That's the only way you'll learn something. Otherwise you'll have trouble to redo this kind of association (and the "has_many :through" isn't easier).

Comment: Ok I worked (I still don't really get why :D), because I adapted my f.select form instead of copying/pasting yours, even thought I thought it was the same thing (I had a prompt instead of an 'include_blank'). Now it, works,thank you !

Comment: Well, it should work even without the "include_blank" ^^ Glad I helped :)